# iOS UINavigationController How to push view controller from left to right when showing right to left languages

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am planning to localize my iOS application where I have a lot of Navigation controllers and a Home Tab car controller as well.

how do I support navigations from left to right (push view controller from left to right) when supporting right-to-left languages? Do we have any direct setting in the UINavigationController so that it will automatically handle navigation direction or do we need to manually push/animate from left to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All standard UIKit components handle LTR/RTL directions automatically. All you need to do is to add a supported language. For example, if the app supports Arabic, and the user set Arabic as their device language, your app will use strings from your Arabic localised strings set (defaulting to your development language if some string is missing,) and the UI will have the RTL direction (including UINavigationController pushing animation.)

Comment: thank you, I just tested it with my existing app by enabling localization. Navigation is working fine.

Comment: just one more query, what if I want to support only one feature localized in my app i.e. some screens and other screens in english. Can we force the Navigation controller direction to right to left for some of the screens?

Comment: I think so, though I haven't tried it myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998944/ios9-force-ltr-uinavigationcontroller-push-direction-for-rtl-languages